# New Google Sign In Service Button Customization

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

In summary: I want to keep my customized button and show a google sign-in popup on click as in the old API.

Detailed:

Since, the old google sign-in API [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button), I want to migrate to [new one](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview).

I have a custom button which is a 70x70 px circle google logo.

I guess google doesn't allow customizing the button anymore. I mean it has some options we can pass but [it's not fully customizable](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator).

It's a known issue as I researched but no solution found yet.

```
google.accounts.id.prompt(notification => {
          if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
            document.cookie = `g_state=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT`
            google.accounts.id.prompt()
          }
        })
```

The code snippet above will only trigger the one-tap If the user has logged in to their Google account before.

If they are not logged in, you'll get an error `opt_out_or_no_session`, what I want is that trigger the google sign-in popup.

So If you want to be popup to appear, you have to render a button after initializing google API. (I am not sure if this is the only way.)

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.querySelector('#element-id'),
          {
            type: 'icon',
            shape: 'pill',
            size: 'large'
          }
        )
```

If user click that button, popup will appear, but I want that behavior on my button not google's.

I tried to put googles button inside my button as a child. set position: absolute, top: 0 and opacity: 0. but I can't change google's button width and height since it's in a IFrame

[[image]]

(don't care opacity for the sake of example)

Any idea to overcome this issue?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtWip.png)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe a custom button is supported in the new api
[see Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/offerings#sign_in_with_google_button)

> Warning: Using your own button is not supported, since there is no API
> to initiate the button flow when your button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. `renderButton()` didn't work because I couldn't style the iframe it produced, so I removed it and used a custom button div.

What worked for me was doing an @click on my button div for a "showGooglePrompt" function that looked like this:

```
showGooglePrompt() {
  window.google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
      // clear g_state cookie if the pop-up has already been closed
      document.cookie =  `g_state=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT`;
      window.google.accounts.id.prompt()
    }
  });
},
```

I also ran `window.google.accounts.id.initialize()` on page load.

Comment: It opens "Google one tap sign in" for me, not the sign in popup. Is it different for you?